# plot responses to 3-level factor over time

Tags: r, plot

I'm new to R and would like to know how to plot things over time.

Part of my experiment involves subjecting grapevines to different levels of water stress. My dependent variable is a measure of water stress (leaf water potential) in the plants (in MPa). My 3-level factor consists of three irrigation treatments. I have four blocks, but some of the data is missing, so the data set is a bit unbalanced. (I actually have two main factors, but I'll keep it simple for now). Here is a taste of some of the data:

```
  date    blk  trt  lwp
05/26/13    2   LD  -1
05/26/13    3   LD  -0.73
05/26/13    4   LD  -0.78
05/26/13    2   SD  -1.15
05/26/13    3   SD  -0.8
05/26/13    4   SD  -0.93
05/26/13    2   ED  -1.2
05/26/13    3   ED  -1.38
05/26/13    4   ED  -1.2
06/20/13    1   LD  -1
06/20/13    2   LD  -1.03
06/20/13    3   LD  -1.05
06/20/13    4   LD  -0.8
06/20/13    1   SD  -1.3
06/20/13    2   SD  -1.28
06/20/13    3   SD  -1.2
06/20/13    4   SD  -1.13
06/20/13    1   ED  -1.35
06/20/13    2   ED  -1.3
06/20/13    3   ED  -1.13
06/20/13    4   ED  -1.08
```

I've managed to figure out how to get the dates into the proper format, and I know how to make VERY basic plots (y~x types), but that's about it.

I'd like to be able to plot each treatment over time on the same graph. That way I have three lines, x axis is by week, and y axis is MPa.

Comment: What do you want to do with the different blocks within the same week & treatment, just ignore them & have multiple points per combination? Average them? Represent them w/ different lines or plotting symbols? (etc)

Comment: The different blocks within the same week & treatment should be averaged.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following 2 examples, depending on how you want to treat block values:

```
d <- read.table("your.data.file.txt", header=T)

# recreate data.frame with correct classes
df <- data.frame(
date = as.Date(strptime(d$date, "%m/%d/%y")),
blk = as.factor(d$blk),
trt = as.factor(d$trt),
lwp = as.numeric(d$lwp))
```

**1: Time trends are plotted from averaged block values. Individual block values are shown as a reference**

```
# require(ggplot2)
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=date, y=lwp, col=trt)) + geom_point() + 
geom_line(stat="summary", fun.y="mean")
```

To separate the treatments for clarity, add `+ facet_wrap(~trt, ncol=3)` to the above code.

**2: Time trends are plotted between matched block values. Unmatched values are left unconnected**

```
# require(ggplot2)    
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=date, y=lwp, col=trt, group=trt:blk)) + geom_point() + 
geom_line()
```

Like above, the `facet_wrap` can be used to separate the treatments.

An example with matched block values is shown below. Graph on the right was generated by adding facet_wrap function:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this (if you want to roll-up the blocks)

```
# if you haven't installed this before, run:> install.packages("ggplot2")
require(ggplot2)

#import the file (I'd saved it to text)
myts<-read.table(file="ts.txt",header=TRUE,sep=" ", row.names=NULL)
# force the date column to Date format
myts$date<-as.Date(myts$date, format="%m/%d/%y")

# I guess you want to average the blocks?
rollup<-aggregate(lwp ~ date * trt, data=myts, FUN=mean)

# call the plot
ggplot(data=rollup) + 
# plot x~y, the col command groups by trt
geom_line(aes(x=date, y=lwp, col=trt))
```

[image]